# What events are fired from Mobile Safari's date/time-type input fields?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, mobile-safari

I'm trying to get events from my web page when the user changes the selected date in the new HTML 5 date / time form input fields. As far as I can tell, neither the `input` nor `change` events are fired in Mobile Safari. Is there some other event that these controls fire, or are there some other common events that input controls fire that I should be watching for?

Answer (score 2):

I am using the 'blur' event in jquery. It seems to be the only one that is firing.